# Shortest script to download file in Node.js with `application/text` header without using any 3rd-party library?

Tags: node.js

I have a Next.js route that sends this as a response:

```js
const data = 'abba dabba jabba'

return new Response(data, {
   headers: { 'content-type': 'application/text' },
})
```

I have a download script that looks like:

```js
import fs from 'fs'
import { consola } from 'consola'

const LOCALHOST_URL = 'http://localhost:3000'

async function main() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const url = `${LOCALHOST_URL}/api/download`
    const fingerprint = 'anon'
    const body = JSON.stringify({ fingerprint })

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body,
    })
    const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer()
    fs.writeFileSync(`file${i}.txt`, buffer)
  }
}

main()
```

> Note: I have to send fingerprint in my real app so I used it here as well.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I had to use `Buffer.from(buffer)` to get it.

```js
import fs from 'node:fs'
import { consola } from 'consola'

const LOCALHOST_URL = 'http://localhost:3000'

async function main() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    const url = `${LOCALHOST_URL}/api/download`
    const fingerprint = 'anon'
    const body = JSON.stringify({ fingerprint })

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body,
    })
    const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer()
    fs.writeFileSync(`file${i}.txt`, Buffer.from(buffer))
  }
  consola.box('Downloaded files successfully!')
}

main()
```